# Xamarin forms xaml button click handler not fired c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I has rey use VS 2015 with xamarin forms to create a cross platform project. I add the xaml page which contain a text box and button. In the code behind, I has code as below

```
public Inno()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   btntest.Clicked += Btntest_Clicked;
 }

Private void Btntest_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name.Text))
    {                
        return;
    }
}
```

When I run the android simulator to test the page, it fire the constructor. But when I clicke the button, it not fire the click event. Anything goes wrong? Please help. Thanks

Comment: Did you try to add a breakpoint inside Btntest_Clicked to see if it's really not executed? I can't see anything wrong apart from the fact that in its current form the method doesn't really do anything.

Comment: Could you add the code/XAML where the button is created?

Comment: @hankide I has put the breakpoint at the click handler.  It not fire the handler when I click the button.

Answer (score 1):

Theres a few things you can try:

1. hook up the event handler in the xaml, see if that works - because you are subscribing to the event in the constructor this shouldn't make a difference functionality wise.

Edit: to do this, in your xaml:

```
<Button Clicked="buttonClicked" />
```

and Press tab when intellisense prompts you to create a new handler.

2. as @hankide said - set a breakpoint and make sure it isn't actually entering it and that the problem isn't the code inside the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your btntest object has been properly mapped to the button on the XAML side of things. By default, XAML objects don't have "names" as you may be accustomed to in WinForms or WebForms and need to have a name property assigned to them. For me, I typically have my buttons marked up as:

```
<Button x:Name=btntest Text="Click Me></Button>
```

Then in the code behind I have to find the button by name in order to wire up the event:

```
var testButton = this.FindByName<Button>("btntest");
testButton.Clicked += Btntest_Clicked;
```

From there everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
btntest.Clicked += new EventHandler(Btntest_Clicked);
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone for the answer...not sure why I close the solution and re-open it, it work fine.